# Histfile in integrated terminal not the same as normal terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just lost my terminal history in VS Code. I noticed it when trying to do a reverse search in the Integrated Terminal (CTRL+R).

To debug, I ran this command:

```bash
echo $HISTFILE
```

This gives me:

```bash
/var/folders/ky/ltbvkg9s1239m5c9bccj5xtc0000gn/T/johndoe-code-zsh/.zsh_history
```

I would expect the normal path of my ZSH history is shown instead, like I get in iTerm2 when running the same command.

```bash
/Users/johndoe/.zsh_history
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by just adding this two lines at the bottom of my ~/.zshrc file.

```bash
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug with VSCode's ZSH shell integration, that has already been resolved on the Insiders version.

Here is the offending line (note the `HISTFILE` without `$`):

[image: Code diff]

I've seen it merged into the [release/1.74](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commits/release/1.74) branch so hopefully, a v1.74.1 is not too far away. In the meanwhile, you can switch to [Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) (side-by-side installation) or turn off shell integration as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the shell integration that's enabled by default ("terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled") and then restart the terminal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ger0.png

Comment: Hi @pgaagj! The history is now visible again with this setting set to "false" but now I'm missing features like conveniently starting the terminal in the root folder of the workspace, links, error detection,...